# Perl: Devel::Gladiator module and memory management

Tags: perl, memory-management

I have a perl script that needs to run in the background constantly. It consists of several `.pm` module files and a main `.pl` file. What the program does is to periodically gather some data, do some computation, and finally update the result recorded in a file.

All the critical data structures are declared in the `.pl` file with `our`, and there's no package variable declared in any `.pm` file.

I used the function `arena_table()` in the `Devel::Gladiator` module to produce some information about the arena in the main loop, and found that the SVs of type `SCALAR` and `GLOB` are increasing slowly, resulting in a gradual increase in the memory usage.

The output of `arena_table` (I reformat them, omitting the title. after a long enough period, only the first two number is increasing):

```
2013-05-17@11:24:34  36235 3924 3661 3642 3376 2401 720 201 27 23 18 13 13 10 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

After running for some time:

```
2013-05-17@12:05:10  50702 46169 36910 4151 3995 3924 2401 720 274 201 26 23 18 13 13 10 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The main loop is something like:

```
our %hash1 = ();
our %hash2 = ();
# and some more package variables ...
# all are hashes

do {
    my $nowtime = time();
    collect_data($nowtime);
    if (calculate() == 1) {
        update();
    }   
    sleep 1;
    get_mem_objects(); # calls arena_table()
} while (1);
```

Except `get_mem_objects`, other functions will operate on the global hashes declared by `our`. In `update`, the program will do some log rotation, the code is like:

```
sub rotate_history() {
    my $i = $main::HISTORY{'count'};
    if ($i == $main::CONFIG{'times'}{'total'}) {
        for ($i--; $i >= 1; $i--) {
           $main::HISTORY{'data'}{$i} = dclone($main::HISTORY{'data'}{$i-1});
        }
    } else {
        for (; $i >= 1; $i--) {
           $main::HISTORY{'data'}{$i} = dclone($main::HISTORY{'data'}{$i-1});
        }
    }

    $main::HISTORY{'data'}{'0'} = dclone(\%main::COLLECT);

    if ($main::HISTORY{'count'} < $main::CONFIG{'times'}{'total'}) {
        $main::HISTORY{'count'}++;
    }
}
```

If I comment the calls to this function, in the final report given by `Devel::Gladiator`, only the SVs of type `SCALAR` is increasing, the number of `GLOB`s will finally enter a stable state. I doubt the `dclone` may cause the problem here.

My questions are,

1. what exactly does the information given by that module mean? The statements in the perldoc is a little vague for a perl newbie like me.
2. And, what are the common skills to lower the memory usage of long-running perl scripts?
3. I know that package variables are stored in the arena, but how about the lexical variables? How are the memory consumed by them managed?

Comment: Could you show some code for the main loop, including the arena thing? The doc says `Returns an array reference containing all the live SVs. Note that this will include a reference back to itself, so you should manually clear this array (via @$arena = ()) when you are done with it, if you don't want to create a memory leak.`. Sounds like you forgot to do that.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks first. I just called `arena_table`, which gives back a string containing the arena information.